# IAM Policy to limit access to S3 Buckets and Object not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to write a simple IAM policy which

1. Gives access to list all the Buckets from the Console (ListAllMyBuckets and GetBucketLocation)
2. Allows to writes files to only one of the s3 buckets.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above policy is still allowing the user to list files from each and every bucket ? I want the user to view the buckets in the console and not the files/folders in the buckets except for one bucket - test.
What is wrong with my policy ?

Thanks

Comment: Do your users have any other s3 access permissions apart from this bucket policy?

Comment: If you _remove_ the above policy, can they still access the other buckets? If so, it means that they are receiving permission from somewhere else -- either other IAM policies, or perhaps a Bucket Policy on those buckets.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way( tool) to find the total access of a user. Looks like the user is getting some additional grants from some other policy.